# Functional variant of get value from if-elseif-else, in Java

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I had to process some json, which could come in slightly different formats (and where I only needed a subset of the json data) and I used JsonPointer (from Jackson) to query the json. I wrote a non-functional solution to the problem, which worked for me, but I wanted to try a functional approach for learning purposes. In the below test program you can see my two solutions. They both work, but the functional solution became quite verbose and I have an annoying warning from Intellij regarding use of get() without isPresent check. I would like to see proposals how to improve the functional implementation and I am happy to see solutions using third-party libraries. The basic problem here, I suppose, is how to model an if-else-if-else, where each branch should return some value, in a functional way.

```
@Test
public void testIt() {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    ImmutableList.of(
            "{ \"foo\": { \"key\": \"1\" } }",
            "{ \"bar\": { \"key\": \"1\" } }",
            "{ \"key\": \"1\" }")
            .forEach(str -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Non-functional: " + getNode(om.readTree(str)));
                    System.out.println("Functional: " + getNodeFunc(om.readTree(str)));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("", e);
                }
            });
}

private JsonNode getNode(JsonNode parentNode) {
    JsonPointer jp1 = JsonPointer.compile("/foo");
    JsonPointer jp2 = JsonPointer.compile("/bar");
    if (!parentNode.at(jp1).isMissingNode()) {
        return parentNode.at(jp1);
    } else if (!parentNode.at(jp2).isMissingNode()) {
        return parentNode.at(jp2);
    }
    return parentNode;
}

private JsonNode getNodeFunc(JsonNode parentNode) {
    BiFunction<JsonNode, String, Optional<JsonNode>> findNode = (node, path) -> {
        JsonPointer jp = JsonPointer.compile(path);
        return node.at(jp).isMissingNode() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(node.at(jp));
    };

    return findNode.apply(parentNode, "/foo")
            .map(Optional::of)
            .orElseGet(() -> findNode.apply(parentNode, "/bar"))
            .map(Optional::of)
            .orElse(Optional.of(parentNode))
            .get(); // Intellij complains here: Optional.get() without isPresent check
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the non-functional code? Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it and I will probably go with it, I was just curious how the problem might be solved using a more functional approach. To learn more

Comment: the thing I feel I learn again and again when trying to write code in a functional style in Java is how much uglier (most) functional code is in Java ;)

Comment: Why are you using `map(Optional::of)`? `findNode.apply()` returns an `Optional<JsonNode>` so you don't need to use `map()`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I felt that way at first too, but after using it with groovy for quite a while and now java, NOT being able to write functionally seems really awkward and restrictive.  Hard to explain until you've done it for a few years and made some new pathways in your brain...  Exceptionally frustrating is that things like if(), try/catch and switch don't return a value leading to ugly syntax like defining a variable to null before setting it in a switch or try/catch.  if() uses the ?: as a functional equivalent, but the syntax is unique and awkward if you split lines.

Comment: @BillK that's a reason to write in Groovy, not a reason to try to write it in Java. I mean, just look at [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54315776/3788176): this code is not an improvement (I'd go so far as to say it's a step or two backwards). "Hard to explain until you've done it for a few years and made some new pathways in your brain" I've worked in functional languages. I think that Java's syntax doesn't lend itself well to the paradigm.

Comment: @AndyTurner Try looking at it from a higher level--it reads like a book.  Filter it (get rid of ones that don't exist), find the first one, return the parentNode.at or the parentNode if it doesn't exist.  To me that's amazingly easy to read, harder to compose perhaps.  Compare that to the question and see which is more readable.  I highly recommend embracing rather than fighting :)

Comment: @AndyTurner Java is still an OO language, with some functional features. It's not a pure functional language. Go to LISP for that, or maybe Haskell. Groovy is just Java with steroids (a lot of them) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would rewrite it to

```
private JsonNode getNodeFunc2(JsonNode parentNode) {
    return Stream.of(JsonPointer.compile("/foo"), JsonPointer.compile("/bar"))
                 .filter(i -> !parentNode.at(i).isMissingNode())
                 .findFirst()
                 .map(parentNode::at)
                 .orElse(parentNode);
}
```

or

```
private JsonNode getNodeFunc3(JsonNode parentNode) {
    return Stream.of(JsonPointer.compile("/foo"), JsonPointer.compile("/bar"))
                 .map(parentNode::at)
                 .filter(Predicate.not(JsonNode::isMissingNode))
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(parentNode);
}
```

or

```
private JsonNode getNodeFunc4(JsonNode parentNode) {
    return Stream.of("/foo", "/bar")
                 .map(JsonPointer::compile)
                 .map(parentNode::at)
                 .filter(Predicate.not(JsonNode::isMissingNode))
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(parentNode);
}
```

because the piece

```
if (!parentNode.at(jp1).isMissingNode()) {
    return parentNode.at(jp1);
} else if (!parentNode.at(jp2).isMissingNode()) {
    return parentNode.at(jp2);
}
```

is code duplication and can be neatly handled by a loop:

```
for (JsonPointer jsonPointer : jsonPointers) {
    JsonNode kid = parentNode.at(jsonPointer);
    if (!kid.isMissingNode()) {
         return kid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Predicate.not() is Java 11? Unfortunately, we're still on Java 8 in the project where I work, but looking to upgrade in near future. Very helpful answer, I learnt from it, which was my objective with this question, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Just something to think about, the `getNode` function is perfect functional code:

- The output depends only on its inputs parameters and its internal algorithm.
- It has no side effects (It doesn't read anything from the outside world or write anything to the outside world)
- It will always return the same output from the same input.